# Condition for meromorphic to imply rational

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, and suppose there exists an $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{-1}(w)$ has at most $m$ points for all $w\in\mathbb{C}$. I want to show that $f(z)$ is a rational function. The first claim I want to show is that, for $w_0$ where the number of points in $f^{-1}(w_0)$ is maximum, $f(z)$ attains values near $w_0$ only near points in $f^{-1}(w_0)$.

The inverse function theorem should work well to establish this claim provided $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ for some $z_0\in f^{-1}(w_0)$. But I cannot see why that has to be true. Is the inverse function theorem a good approach to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f^{-1}(w_0)$ has maximal cardinality $k$ among all fibres, then you must have $f'(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in f^{-1}(w_0)$. For If $f$ attains the value $w_0$ with multiplicity $m_j$ in $z_j \in f^{-1}(w_0)$, then there is an $r_j > 0$ and a neighbourhood $V_j$ of $z_j$ such that every $w \in D_{r_j}(w_0)\setminus\{w_0\}$ is attained in $m_j$ distinct points in $V_j$. Choosing $r_j$ small enough for all $z_j \in f^{-1}(w_0)$, so that the corresponding $V_j$ are disjoint, every $w \in D_{\min \{r_j : 1\leqslant j \leqslant k\}}(w_0)\setminus\{w_0\}$ is attained at $m_j$ times in $v_j$, hence

$$\operatorname{card} f^{-1}(w) \geqslant \sum_{j=1}^k m_j,$$

and if any $m_j > 1$, the fibres of such a $w$ would have cardinality $> k$.

From that we deduce that $f$ has at most $k$ poles, hence $\infty$ is an isloated singularity of $f$. By Picard's theorem (Casorati-Weierstraß is sufficient), $\infty$ cannot be an essential singularity of $f$, hence $f$ must be rational.

Comment: That helps me see how we are guaranteed finitely many poles, but I still don't see why $f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in f^{-1}(w_0)$.

Comment: If you had $f'(z_1) = 0$ for some $z_1 \in f^{-1}(w_0)$, then for all $w \in D_\rho(w_0)\setminus\{w_0\}$, where $\rho > 0$ is sufficiently small, you'd have at least two points close to $z_1$ mapped to $w$, and at least one close to all other elements of the fibre $f^{-1}(w_0)$. That would mean the fibre $f^{-1}(w)$ contains more points than $f^{-1}(w_0)$. But $w_0$ was chosen so that the cardinality of the fibre is maximal.