# Meromorphic Function is Rational

Tags: complex-analysis

**I'm asking for clarity on the method given above. If there is a duplicate post, it is only duplicate if it addresses this. Thx!**

Let $f(z)$ be a meromorphic function on the complex plane, and suppose there is an integer $m$ such that $f^{-1}(w)$ has at most $m$ points for all $w \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that $f(z)$ is a rational function.

---

A hint/solution has it that we can:

*Choose $w_0$ such that the number of points in $f^{-1}(w_0)$ is maximum. Then $f(z)$ attains values $w$ near $w_0$ only near points in $f^{-1}(w_0)$, $\frac{1}{f(z)-w_0}$ is bounded at $\infty$, and $f(z)$ is meromorphic on ${\mathbb{C}^*}$ hence rational.*

That $f(z)$ attains values $w$ near $w_0$ only near points in $f^{-1}(w_0)$ is evident by the Opening Mapping theorem, but what of boundedness at infinity? How does this with $f(z)$ being meromorphic make $f(z)$ rational? Are we using Liouville's theorem here?

Comment: I've asked questions about the hint/solution. The posting you've linked does not address those.

Comment: Upon further study, I don't think the question I pointed to actually answers your question.  To answer the first of your queries, it seems to me that if,  for some $\epsilon,\delta>0$, we have $|f(z)-w_0|>\epsilon$ whenever $\mathrm{dist}(z,f^{-1}(w_0))>\delta$, then for large enough $|z|$ we will have $\mathrm{dist}(z,f^{-1}(w_0))>\delta$ and thus $|1/(f(z)-w_0)|<1/\epsilon$.  This in turn implies that $1/(f(z)-w_0)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}^*=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, since there are only a finite number of poles.  Not sure of the final conclusion that $f(z)$ is rational.

Comment: Ok, your first statement concerning the distances we can assert by the Open Mapping theorem? Then, that $1/(f(z)-w_0)$ has a removable singularity is a consequence of  [Riemann's theorem of removable singularities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem). This in turn implies that a removable singularity is attained on $\mathbb{C}^*$ and thus $1/(f(z)-w_0)$ is meromorphic.

Comment: I am unable to convince myself that the open mapping theorem (Rudin *Real and Complex Analysis* 10.32) implies the statement I made.  My statement was just an effort to translate into more precise language the hint "$f(z)$ attains values $w$ near $w_0$ only near points in $f^{−1}(w_0)$."  There is a supposed proof of the latter imprecise statement in the question to which I pointed, but I don't understand it.

Comment: Can you remove the duplicate flag?

Comment: By your reference to "flag," you seem to mean that I delete the comment in which I suggested that your question might be a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/585965/condition-for-meromorphic-to-imply-rational?rq=1, to which I also referred in my last comment.  I will remove the comment.

Comment: Rather this, 

"This question may already have an answer here:
Condition for meromorphic to imply rational 1 answer" at the top of my post. However, judging from your comment, it may be that only I can see it.

Comment: I do not control the text you see, and I do not see it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: There is an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert f(z) - w_0\rvert < \varepsilon \implies \operatorname{dist}(z, f^{-1}(w_0)) < \delta$. The set $f^{-1}(w_0)$ is finite, hence bounded, and thus there is an $R$ with $\lvert z\rvert > R \implies \lvert f(z)-w_0\rvert \geqslant \varepsilon$. Hence the meromorphic function $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z) - w_0}$ is bounded in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, so $g$ is in fact meromorphic on the whole sphere, i.e. it's a rational function. But then $f(z) = w_0 + \frac{1}{g(z)}$ is rational.

Comment: @DanielFischer What properties of $f$ are you using to conclude that such $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ exist?

Comment: @user193319 The finiteness condition on the fibres, and the local mapping properties of nonconstant holomorphic functions. Let $f^{-1}(w_0) = \{z_1, \dotsc, z_k\}$. Find $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert z_i - z_j\rvert > 2\delta$ for $i \neq j$, and all poles of $f$ have distance $> \delta$ from each $z_i$. Since $f$ is an open mapping, for each $i$ there is $\varepsilon_i > 0$ such that $D_{\varepsilon_i}(w_0) \subset f(D_{\delta}(z_i))$. Let $\varepsilon = \min \{\varepsilon_1, \dotsc, \varepsilon_k\}$. If $\lvert w-w_0\rvert < \varepsilon$,

Comment: then $f^{-1}(w)$ has (at least) one point in each $D_{\delta}(z_i)$. But $w_0$ was chosen to have a fibre of maximal cardinality, hence $w$ cannot have more than $k$ preimages. Thus $f^{-1}(w) \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{k} D_{\delta}(z_i)$ (and each $D_{\delta}(z_i)$ contains only one point of $f^{-1}(w)$). This holds for all $w$ with $\lvert w - w_0\rvert < \varepsilon$, hence $$f^{-1}\bigl(D_{\varepsilon}(w_0)\bigr) \subset \bigcup_{i = 1}^{k} D_{\delta}(z_i)\,.$$